# How to verify a user is signed in

Tags: angular, security

**Sign in process**

So when the user wants to sign in, they'll enter their credentials, and if correct, a `session_id` and a `user_info` cookie will be created. The `session_id` is httponly and the `user_info` is not. The `user_info` cookie contains some basic info about the user including their `id` (an arbitrary number).


**How I am verifying a user is signed in**

So what I'm doing right now to verify that a user is signed in, is I simply check to see if the `user_info` cookie is set. And I put this check in an auth guard protecting all my app's routes. I figured this would be secure because even if an attacker were to create a false `user_info` cookie, my API still verifies the identity of the user by making sure the user from the `user_info` cookie matches the `session_id`, which results in a database hit.


**Best way to do it?**

What I'm wondering is, I don't know if this is the best way to do it or not. I'm wondering I should put the functionality of hitting the database to verify the user's session in the auth guard or not. That is, instead of simply checking if the `user_info` cookie is set.


**Quick note**

Sorry I didn't put any code on this post. I couldn't think of anything that would be useful to include.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the user_info cookie is not needed at all. You can use the session id from the httponly cookie to look up and find any info about the user. This is how any traditional session implementation works, and it is still the most secure against many threats IF and only if implemented correctly. As this is very standard, you should not implement it though - the server side language you are using most probably has it implemented already. Any custom implementation will likely contain weaknesses or vulnerabilities, because this has a lot of depth and not easy to get right.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Yea, the user_info cookie is needed because it contains an id which is used for various API requests. Sorry, I'm not fully understanding what you're saying so please clarify. If I don't have this cookie, how would I get info about the user?

Comment: If the api can cross-check with the session id whether that id from user_info is valid for the session, why not just use the session id to call the api? There is everything necessary for the api to identify the user - because it needs to anyway. Am I not getting something? :) A session id authenticates a user, nothing else is needed, everything can be retrieved server-side, and this is also good for security.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My session id can be used to call the API because it authenticates the user. But I'm not sure you are fully understanding what I'm asking. I'm simply wondering how I should implement a guard to even let the user in to certain routes on the website. Yea, to load up the actual data and what-not the website will be displaying for a user, those API endpoints will be behind authentication of the user's session id. I'm just wondering, how on the UI side, I can simply validate a user is signed in.

Comment: Ah ok, it was indeed a misunderstanding. On the client side, you can't prevent the user from displaying any of your app pages. It's all downloaded to the client, there is nothing that could keep the user from having a look if he wants to. But that's ok, it's just page structures. Data is the only important thing here, and that must be authorized on the server - based on the session id. Don't put much effort into trying to "hide" pages on the client, because that's pretty much impossible and that's fine.

Comment: Having said that, of course for UX reasons you may want to tailor views, so the server can indicate whether the user is logged in or not, maybe the role too if there is a role conecpt, but always keep in mind that this is not for security. Most of the security must be implemented on the server when the client is accessing data (there are considerations for the client too, but those are mostly unrelated to this question).

Comment: You can encrypt value of `user_info` with algorithms like AES, key used is stored in server. Without the key, attacker is unable to create a valid cookie.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Awesome, you've answered my question perfectly. And yea, I've should've mentioned about roles and stuff like that, because the data stored in user_info is related to that. As long as I'm hard securing everything in the API based on the user's session id, I should be fine.

Comment: @FlilyHsu Thanks for the idea, but I unfortunately need to actually access the data in the user_info cookie form the UI, so I'd need to also decrypt it from the UI. Therefore, in my opinion, it'd be pointless to even implement AES because the decryption process would be completely exposed.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Feel free to convert your comment(s) into an answer on this post and I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: @FlilyHsu Note that the purpose of encryption is not that. What you mean is message authentication, which is a different concept, ie. you can authenticate unencrypted messages (this is for example HMAC), and also you can include authentication in encryption (for example AES-GCM, but not other AES modes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, you meant verifying if the user is signed in **on the client**.

As a generic rule of thumb, any authorization on the client is a nice user experience feature, but *has nothing to do with security*. You cannot prevent a user from having a look at any page in your Angular app, because it's all downloaded to the client and they have full control over it.

All authorization and access control **on data** must take place on the server, ie. the server must authenticate the user (based on the session id in your case), perform any necessary authorization steps, and only serve data that is appropriate. If this is the case, having access to page structures (html+css without data, and javascript code*) is fine.

*A sidenote on javascript. You should not rely on security by obscurity, and any javascript should be secure against client-side threats (like for example XSS, open redirection and similar). You should treat any javascript code as already known to any user or attacker. However, that is not always the case, and it raises the complexity of an attack if javascript is obfuscated. Note that obfuscation is not a primary security feature in the sense that it's not ok to hide vulnerable code by obfuscation, but you can argue that obfuscation does make attacks more difficult for people who don't know the code - and hence, it does make some sense.

Also there is a data leak aspect.

You are using the user_info cookie to store data about your user so that Angular can access it. This is fine for non-sensitive data like user id, maybe role ids and similar. However, sensitive stuff (even including an email address for example) should not be stored in a cookie, let alone in a non-httponly one.

Needless to say that user_info is only for the client, as it is not authentic, a user can just change it to whatever values. It **must not** be used on the server for any kind of a decision (like authorization).

Instead of a cookie, it would probably be beneficial to generate necessary data into the page itself (meta headers for example) so that Angular can read it from there, and not store them in a cookie, because cookies are cached, saved to disk and so on. But this goes well into the UX aspect.